# Bing Image Search API filter by format

Tags: image, azure, bing

I'm using this query https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=delhaize%20logo to connect to the Bing Image Search API and find the desired image. This works very good, but I like Bing to return only jpg and png images. I cannot find anywhere how to filter on image format with Bing.

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560913.aspx) page regarding image filters but it doesn't mention image format anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no method to filter by image format. You could do this though (php):

```
$word = 'monitor';
$extension = 'jpg';

$request = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Image?$format=json&Query=%27'.urlencode($word).'%27&Adult=%27Strict%27&ImageFilters=%27Size%3AMedium%2BAspect%3AWide%2BColor%3AColor%2BStyle%3APhoto%27';
$process = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  "$accountKey:$accountKey");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($process);
$json = json_decode($response, true);

if(is_array($json['d']['results'])) {
    foreach($json['d']['results'] as $image) {
        if(pathinfo($image['MediaUrl'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == $extension) {
            # update values
            $urls[] = $image['MediaUrl'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($urls);
```

This will find images that match the "monitor" string, and then you just filter them in php.